# How deep should post holes be in central PA for a five foot wooden fence and should I use concrete?

Tags: concrete, fence

I understand this question is asked a lot all over the internet but I cannot find a specific answer for my circumstances. I'm hoping someone with a better understanding can chime in and provide some guidance. Specific questions at the bottom.

### Environmental Factors

1. **Location**: South-central Pennsylvania, near Harrisburg. It gets very cold for a long time during the winters. Plenty of snow and ice.
2. **Frost Line**: The frost line is officially 44 inches throughout all of Pennsylvania. I cannot find anything more specific for our County.
3. **Soil**: We live amongst farms and fields if that means anything. The soil is officially SILT LOAM according to County records. Inspecting the soil myself, I found that it is dry and heavily compacted. It breaks apart almost like soft rock, but it doesn't roll up or stick to itself like clay. There is clay around the foundation of the house itself, but I haven't found it where we plan to put the fence posts.
4. **Wind**: Wind is a problem here with incredibly strong gusts that have blown the siding off the house a few times.
5. **Animals**: Dogs and goats will be the primary contenders for the fence. The dogs are as big as 150 lbs. and trained but they play rough and will likely run into the fence at some point. Goats are goats.
6. **Gates**: We will have a large 10 to 14 ft. double-gate so vehicles/tractors can get through if needed.

### Fence Style and Use

The goal is to keep dogs and goats in and critters out. We are going for a three-rail styled farm fence that will be 5 ft. high off the ground and have a wire mesh between the rails. This style is for visual purposes, as well as to mitigate the high winds. We'll be using 4x4 pressure treated posts. We'll probably need to do 6x6 posts for the large double-gate, depending on the final size.

### Questions

**Depth and Gravel**
Frost line is 44 inches. Most sources I could find recommend going 6 inches below the frost line so that puts us at 50 inches. Does this 6 inch rule factor in the recommended 6 inches of gravel? Because that would put the base of the post right back at the frost line. Should the hole in-fact be 56 inches down so that the post itself is below the frost line?

**Concrete or Dirt**
Given the above factors, would it be better to fill the holes with concrete or just compact with dirt? I understand the pros and cons of each method and am prepared to deal with either, I would just like to know if a dirt-only solution will be sturdy enough.

**Gate and Corner Posts**
Should gate and corner posts be concreted in regardless for extra stability and support?

Comment: Typical guideline is 1/3 of the above ground height, living where I do, however, I have no knowledge of frost line.

Comment: That's the issue I'm facing. The guideline makes sense until you realize that 1/3 of the above ground height is a solid 2 feet above the frost line; the depth that many other guides say to go down to.

Comment: I did a fence for a cow for a friend and put 4ft of 8" square post in the ground for a 5ft post height ie it was 9ft long. These were the corner posts and the intermediate posts were 4" that went in 3ft. relatively soft soil with stones but the cow did not damage the fence when scratching.

Comment: If the fencing is wire, the posts can move some (from frost) without the fence destroying itself. If it's more rigid (cattle panels or wooden boards, and you propose boards) movement will destroy it faster. Boards also invite much more wind pressure from your *incredibly strong gusts.* Fences are pretty much always a tradeoff between what you want and what you can afford. Posts below frost line is definitely better, but also definitely costs a lot more.